# Is it possible to test Google App Engine OpenID authentication on development Server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid

I'm trying [OpenID](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/articles/openid.html) support for Google App Engine on a small project i have on my machine but when i call:

`users.create_login_url(federated_identity = provider_url)`

i get this error:

```
google_appengine/google/appengine/api/user_service_pb.py", line 178, in ByteSize
    n += self.lengthString(len(self.destination_url_))
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

provider_url is `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`

any clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should normally pass a `dest_url` parameter to `create_login_url`, unless you're certain that there is a "current request" whose url you want to use instead.  Apparently, the latter condition does not obtain, so the destination url stays `None`, which causes the problem you're observing.  Passing an explicit `dest_url` should fix it.

Comment: that did the trick, many thanks. I don't understand when you say "unless you're certain that there is a "current request" whose url you want to use instead".

Comment: @system, if you're in the middle of responding to a request (and the destination URL for the login is exactly the URL that request is asking you to serve) then you shouldn't have to repeat that bit of info in `dest_url` (though it can't hurt if you do, the system should be able to deduce it on your behalf if you don't pass it).