# Google app engine Federated (openid) login localhost

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, openid

I am trying to use [this](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/articles/openid.html#ex) script for federated login with google's app engine. This works on the deployed app engine but with localhost it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/python/app_en/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 515, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/workspace/python/app_en/bingousie/helloworld.py", line 23, in get
    p['login_url'] = users.create_login_url(federated_identity=p_url)
  File "/workspace/python/app_en/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/users.py", line 216, in create_login_url
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('user', 'CreateLoginURL', req, resp)
  File "/workspace/python/app_en/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 86, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/workspace/python/app_en/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 286, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/workspace/python/app_en/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 149, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/workspace/python/app_en/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub.py", line 73, in MakeSyncCall
    if request.ByteSize() > self.__max_request_size:
  File "/workspace/python/app_en/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/user_service_pb.py", line 178, in ByteSize
    n += self.lengthString(len(self.destination_url_))
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Is this because the openid servers do not allow logging in to local site? If it is then it why doesn't it at least work with [myopenid.com](http://myopenid.com) (I use it for my django openid authentication on local server).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `create_login_url` call you should specify the `dest_url` parameter.

> dest_url can be full URL or a path
>   relative to your application's domain.

I had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489488/is-it-possible-to-test-google-app-engine-openid-authentication-on-development-ser).